# PHP form does not submit

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, forms

I want to submit the form  after an `if` statement for example:

```
<?Php
if($something){

?>
<script type="text/javascript">
    document.getElementById('dateForm').submit(); // SUBMIT FORM
</script>
<form  id="dateForm" action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="POST">

<input type="hidden" name="test" value="test">
<input type="hidden" name"test2" value="Support">



</form>
<?php

}
?>
```

However, this doesn't work.

Comment: Among other things, I think you need a `>` after the `?` before you escape PHP and begin your `script` tags.

Comment: What does "doesn't work" mean? Do you get an error? You may need to View Source to see it.

Comment: i get notihng no error but the form doesnt get submit it doesnt take me to paypal

Comment: thanks guys i got it fixed i just had to put the script after the form not before the form,and yeah you had a point @underscroe i just forgot to put it on the example not on my code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put the script after the form tag. It searches dateForm id and until that no form is in the output so it does nothing. When you place that after it, it'll search the page for that id and it finds that and submits.

```
<?Php
if($something):?>

<form  id="dateForm" action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="POST">
<input type="hidden" name="test" value="test">
<input type="hidden" name"test2" value="Support">
</form>

<script type="text/javascript">
    document.getElementById('dateForm').submit(); // SUBMIT FORM
</script>

<?php
endif;?>
```

Comment: thanks!!!! it worked :)

Comment: how do i submit it in a new tab??

Comment: nvm it does in a new tab,ty

Comment: nvm it does in a new tab,ty